# Content based request routing in cloud foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Istio which is often used with Kubernetes support content based routing:

https://istio-releases.github.io/v0.1/docs/tasks/request-routing.html

E.g. you can set a header and influence routing per user (for example).

Is this possible in Cloud foundry?

Comment: Can you be more specific? How do you want to influence routing? There's support for sticky sessions in CF, which influences routing, there's also a header you can set to pin you request to a specific app instance, and you can of course do a decent amount with routes & paths. There's nothing to say that if a certain header exists, requests with that header would be routed to a specific app. You would have to use Jan's solution for that.

Comment: I want to allow developers and deploy their own version of an app to a shared CF space. When the developer would login into the developed  application routing would need to make sure that instead of the default version of the app the developer specific version is used. I guess yes, Jan's proposal below would be the way to go

Comment: How would you identify an incoming request as needing to go to a developer specific version of the app? If you got to www.example.com and that normally goes to example-app, how would you know that a request to www.example.com should go to example-dev1-app?

Comment: routing would be based on an http header being set with some specific value

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine [Route Service](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/route-services.html), which will be bound to the multiple CF apps. Of course, you will need to code own route logic.

In theory you may write Istio wrapper code, so Istio will act as a CF route service.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to deploy a reverse proxy app in front of your set of apps. For example, a request flow would look like this:

```
Client -> Load Balancers -> Gorouter -> Proxy App -> Actual App
```

This would be [very similar to route services](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/services/route-services.html#architecture), but I think it offers some advantages. The Proxy App to Actual App connection could be done over the container network, so I think you could remove some hops as compared to route services, and similar to route services, you could prevent direct access to your actual apps. That said, you could proxy to the route of your Actual App too, it would just take a second pass through the LB & Gorouters.

You could use Apache Web Server, Nginx or even [Spring Cloud Gateway](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-gateway) if you wanted something that could be extremely flexible with how it routes.

Anyway, not drastically different but it's a slightly different option.